# jQuery Star Rating Plugin callback function with previously default set value

Tags: jquery, rating, rating-system

I am using the [jQuery Star Rating Plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/). When the page is loaded a dynamic value should be set with the posibility of changing that in a jquery dialog with the new selected value. I have something like this:

```
    $("input#currentRatingDisplay").rating('select', '${rating}');// dynamic value that does not get selected?!?   

    $("input#currentRatingDisplay").rating({
        callback: function(value, link){
            $("#rateIt").rating('select', value, false); // stars in ui dialog to get persisted in the db  
                $("#dialog-rating" ).dialog("open");
            }
    });
```

The callback function with value transfer to the stars in dialog works but the problem is that the initial rating is not selected. Any ideas? Also - is there a way to get read of the reset button?
Thanks.

Comment: Does `alert('${rating}');` show a value?

Comment: Hi Sander, going through debugging §{rating} gets replaced. If I removed the callback part it will get properly displayed. I will try later with alert - thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for javascript to do that. As the site says: Use the checked property to specify the initial/default value of the control.

So something like:

```
<c:forEach var="random" items="${item}">
   <c:if test="${fn:item == rating}">
      <input name="star2" type="radio" class="star" checked="checked"/>
   <c: else>
      <input name="star2" type="radio" class="star"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Hey Elger, thanks for the answer. I had forgotten to mention that the initial value is dynamic, I get it from a spring model.

Comment: I'm not familiar with spring but I updated the answer with some spring pseudo code. Hope it's clear where i'm getting at. This way you don't have to do any tricks with javascript afterwards.

Comment: Great, it works - thanks for the suggestion Elger, it is so elegant.